Forminator WP plugin conditional logic follow up suggestioning post question
I have the following issue. I am developing a survey with the Forminator WP plugin. It needs to use conditional logic, and for questions with selectable answers, it should provide a specific article that corresponds to the question as a suggestion on the next page after completing the survey. This applies to questions answered with "NO." I assume I need to set the IDs of the respective articles and configure it so that selecting the corresponding answer displays the respective article, but I am not sure exactly how to do this.
I tried using the base feautures but cant seem to amke is work.

Welcome! Why don't you ask the plugin developer? Seems like they would be the best one to ask.
